# nested for loop giving irrelevant output

Tags: php, for-loop, nested-loops

I want to print value from `1` to `user_input_limit`. But after every 4 value. there should be 1 break line, and for that i am using below code, which is not working. It repeats value from `+1` in 2nd interation.

My Code :-

```
if(is_numeric($_GET['num'])) {
    $num = ceil($_GET['num']/4);

    for($i=1;$i<=$num;$i++) {

       echo '<div class="hello">';

        for($j=$i;$j<=$i+3;$j++) {
            echo $j.", ";
        }

       echo '</div>';

        echo '<br />';
    }
}
```

This works good for first row, but in next row , `j` becomes `2` which is not what i need , i want it to be `5`. Like below

**What i need :-** 
`User_input` = 11

```
<div class='hello'>1,  2,  3,  4, </div> 
<div class='hello'>5,  6,  7,  8, </div>
<div class='hello'>9, 10,  11, </div>
```

My inside for loop is wrong and i am getting output like :-

**What i am getting :-**

```
1,  2,  3,  4, 
2,  3,  4,  5, 
3,  4,  5,  6,
```

Can any one fix my algorithm.

Thanks

Comment: Be careful, you wrote `for($j=1;$j<=$i+3;$j++)` instead of `for($j=$i;$j<=$i+3;$j++)` which correspond to your current output.

Comment: fixed my typo. Thanks

Comment: Is that <br /> really necessary with your div stuff now ?

Comment: yes :).. Cause i am not styling it with margin-bottom...

Comment: It's been a while since last time I've done web development, but isn't `display:block` what you want to do?

Comment: No, bro, I am currently with bootstrap, and few things are different considering not messing bootstrap much :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use an inner loop.

```
if(is_numeric($_GET['num'])) {
    for($i=1;$i<=$_GET['num'];$i++) {
        if ($i % 4 == 1) {
            echo '<div class="hello">';
        }
        echo $i.", ";
        if ($i % 4 == 0 || $i == $_GET['num']) {
            echo '</div>';
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

If you are wondering if it would be possible to use a nested loop, here a possible solution:

```
if(is_numeric($_GET['num'])) {
    for($i=0;$i<ceil($_GET['num']/4);$i++) {
        echo '<div class="hello">';
        for($j=$i*4+1;$j<=$i*4+4 && $j <= $_GET['num'];$j++) {
            echo $j.", ";
        }
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
```

As you can notice, it's ugly :).

Comment: Actually i missed whole div while typing them. Updated my current code. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For div-ed strings is:

```
if(is_numeric($_GET['num'])) {
    echo '<div class="hello">';

    for($i=1;$i<=$_GET['num'];$i++) {
        echo $i . ($i < $_GET['num'] ? ', ' : '');

        if ($i % 4 == 0) {
            echo '</div>' . ($i < $_GET['num'] ? '<div class="hello">' : '');
        }
    }

    echo $_GET['num'] % 4 ? '</div>' : '';
}
```

Comment: For num == 4, you may have unexpected result. Also I assume that your last `<div>` is in fact `</div>`.

Comment: Updated and tested. )))) BTW, a comma will not output if it is the last num.

Comment: Instead of putting the result of `$_GET['num'] % 4` into a variable and use a ternary operator. Why didn't you just wrote `if ($_GET['num'] % 4) echo '</div>';` at the end?

Comment: About the comma, OP wants it according to its expected output example. :)

Comment: @Maxime, when I wrote it I thought I will use it more than once. :)) Deleted. Thanks for the point.

Comment: Yeah, but again, why using a ternary operator is that case? Do you believe that `echo $_GET['num'] % 4 ? '</div>' : '';` is more readable than `if ($_GET['num'] % 4) echo '</div>';`?

Comment: @Maxime, About the comma, I'm sure he will ask "how to output without the last comma". Because as I can see, his initial conditions was changed.

Comment: @Maxime, It is pretty readable, I think. It is not a kind of `$_GET['num'] % 4 ? '</div>' : ($_GET['num'] % 5 ? 'some text' : '')`, so it is pretty good for the situation.

Comment: @Maxime, also good style of coding is add curly brackets for `if` even only one statement will execute in the condition. It is exactly for improving readability. Plus, any statement inside the `if` must be placed on another line. So, as a result, good style for your example will be: `if ($_GET['num'] % 4) { [NEW STRING] echo '</div>'; [NEW STRING] }`. It is good in the situation when you paid not for quality but for strings count. )) I usually paid for the quality of code not for the volume.

Comment: Also, it is pretty readable because I've used it in short string. In the long and complex string with a lot of concatenations I would consider to split the statement to few statements and use `if` statement instead of ternary operator.

Comment: I still prefer an `if` :). Anyway, +1 for your answer because I think it works ;).

Answer (score 0):

Why not just

```
if(is_numeric($_GET['num'])) {
    $num = intval($_GET['num']);
    for($i=1;$i<=$num;$i++) {
        echo "$i, ";
        if(!($i%4)) echo '<br />';
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think using `is_numeric` and `intval` for one variable is a little excessive work. ))

Comment: @geomagas, bro, i made type and missed whole div. Updated my code. Thanks

Comment: Oh, come on! That's a whole different problem!